# Why was I just deducted 27 rep?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, down-votes

My 'achievements' tab just showed -27 for [this answer](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1076/529).

I don't remember the previous vote count on this answer and don't have enough rep to see the vote split, so I'm wondering if I was downvoted (without explanation) once, a gazillion times, or if this is just a bug and the answer wasn't downvoted at all.

Comment: looks like someone downvoted every answer to that question except one

Comment: @Zanna Weird. I feel downvotes should be used to signal a problem with an answer, not to promote another one. An additional comment explaining the problem would be ideal.

Comment: Yeah I feel the same about use of downvotes, but some people think differently :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [your reputation history](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/529/henning?tab=reputation), you got an unaccept, unupvote, and a downvote:

[image]

Apparently the OP came back and decided to unaccept the answer, and presumably take their upvote away and downvote instead. As to *why*, I don't know - perhaps they found proof against your answer?

Comment: Interesting, thanks